# rain plugin in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to breeze rain are petals of flowers as whole through my website. Now i am currently showering show by using `snowfall` jquery plugin.

***Is there is any plugin to shower rain or petals of flowers.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this: http://rain-demo.heroku.com/

Library is here: https://github.com/juliocesar/rain.js

Comment: There is no continuity in rain. whether there is a plugin to shower petals of flowers

Comment: @Mohan what do you mean, no continuity?

Comment: rain not continues with same speed some times its struck up